# How to place any logic gate in Ultiboard 10

Tags: digital-logic, ultiboard

I have enormous problem with Ultiboard 10 Student's edition. I can not find any logic gate in this program. Where the AND/OR/NOT/NAND/NOR logic gates in this program?

[image: http://s14.postimage.org/4ydbf8yxd/das.png]

Comment: I can get access into Utilboard database, but there are many devices, LCDs, LEDs etc... but no logic gates.

Comment: Please Brian, help me with that. If i find those gates half of the problem is solved.

Comment: What do you see if you open the folder called "IC"? Also, do you understand that Ultiboard is just a PCB layout tool? Based on a brief perusal of the [NI website](http://www.ni.com/ultiboard/), it seems you're supposed to do your schematic capture in Multisim, and the transfer the design to Ultiboard for layout.

Answer (score 2):

Ultiboard is for your finished schematic. You import it from multisim to generate a netlist and then auto route or manually route your traces to export your pcb layout to a gerber file for fabrication.  Multisim is where you will do the schematic and they definitely have logic gates.  If for some reason you still cant find them logic gates can be fabricated with NFETs and PFETs